# bootstrap popover does not refresh with ajax content on dropdownlist selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdownlist for in MVC view where the first option and last option are always

'Please Select' and 'Other'.

When a user selects any other option other than the above two, a popover should appear with a partial view in it and should
refresh for every selected item Other than the above two.

The below code displays the partial view on the popover but does not refresh the content when any other dropdownlist item
(apart from 'Please Select' and 'Other') is selected.

The popover just displays the same content for all the dropdownlist items including the 'Please Select' and 'Other'.

I do not want pop over to appear for 'Please Select' and 'Other'.
For the remaining options, popover should refresh its content based on the selection in dropdownlist.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedIncident, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIncident, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"),  new {  data_toggle="popover", @class = "form-control ", @id = "IncidentId" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedIncident, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="divOtherIncident" style="display:none;">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherIncident, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherIncident, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tbOtherIncident"} })             
            </div>
        </div>


        $("#IncidentId").change(function (e) {              
            var ddlVal = $("#IncidentId option:selected").val();            
            if (ddlVal == "16") {   
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('destroy');
                $('#divOtherIncident').show();
            }
            if (ddlVal != "" && ddlVal != "16") {                   
                $('#divOtherIncident').hide();
                $("#tbOtherIncident").val("");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetIncidentDetails")',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: { id: $("#IncidentId").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("[data-toggle='popover']").attr('data-content', data);                                                        
                        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
                            html: true
                        }).popover('show');                         
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve action details' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
            if (ddlVal == "")
            {                   
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('destroy');                    
                $('#divOtherIncident').hide();
                $("#tbOtherIncident").val("");
            }
        });
```

partial view:

```
<div class="popover-content" >
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.ActionTaken, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-1"})
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ActionTaken, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.AdviceGiven, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-1" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AdviceGiven, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: content is refreshing by the code below. Left task is to prevent popover on 'Please select' and 'Other' options.success: function (data) {
       $("[data-toggle='popover']").attr('data-content', data);              
       $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
        html: true
       }).popover('show');

Comment: Got both issues resolved. Not sure how can I reply to my own post. wherever popover is not required $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('disable');  And where popup is required----$("[data-toggle='popover']").attr('data-content', data);              
       $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
        html: true
       }).popover('enable').popover('show');

Comment: please click on `edit` link to update your question